# How do I get continous days count in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with respect to invoice data. I want to calculate a column **Days_to_next_invoice2** as below which gives the number of days left for the next invoice, which can be calculated from the Invoice_Date column, However there are some nan values in Invoice Date column since no invoices were generated on these days. I was able to calculate Days_to_next_invoice as per below code but I would like my data to be like Days_to_next_invoice2. Any suggestion is appreciated.
Days_to_next_invoice attribute description: It is the difference between the invoice dates. Example: 3/14/2018 - 3/13/2018 = 1 day. 3/19/2018 - 3/14/2018 = 5 days

```
Date    Invoice_Date    Days_to_next_invoice    Days_to_next_invoice2
3/13/2018   3/13/2018   1                            1
3/14/2018   3/14/2018   5                            5
3/15/2018   nan        nan                           4
3/16/2018   nan        nan                           3
3/17/2018   nan        nan                           2
3/18/2018   nan        nan                           1
3/19/2018   3/19/2018   4                            4
3/20/2018   nan        nan                           3
3/21/2018   nan        nan                           2
3/22/2018   nan        nan                           1
3/23/2018   3/23/2018   4                            4
3/24/2018   nan        nan                           3
3/25/2018   nan        nan                           2
3/26/2018   nan        nan                           1
3/27/2018   3/27/2018   0                            0
```

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between below lines how you come to the output of 1 in first tow and 5 in second row:
`Date    Invoice_Date    Days_to_next_invoice    Days_to_next_invoice2
3/13/2018   3/13/2018   1                            1
3/14/2018   3/14/2018   5                            5`

Comment: @RSM  It is the difference between the invoice dates. 3/14/2018  - 3/13/2018 = 1 day. 3/19/2018 - 3/14/2018 = 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mask of `Days_to_next_invoice` by `isnull`, and then `groupby` and `cumcount` with `ascending=False` :

```
s = df["Days_to_next_invoice"].isnull()

df.loc[s,"Days_to_next_invoice"] = s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False)+1

print (df)

         Date Invoice_Date  Days_to_next_invoice  Days_to_next_invoice2
0   3/13/2018    3/13/2018                   1.0                      1
1   3/14/2018    3/14/2018                   5.0                      5
2   3/15/2018          NaN                   4.0                      4
3   3/16/2018          NaN                   3.0                      3
4   3/17/2018          NaN                   2.0                      2
5   3/18/2018          NaN                   1.0                      1
6   3/19/2018    3/19/2018                   4.0                      4
7   3/20/2018          NaN                   3.0                      3
8   3/21/2018          NaN                   2.0                      2
9   3/22/2018          NaN                   1.0                      1
10  3/23/2018    3/23/2018                   4.0                      4
11  3/24/2018          NaN                   3.0                      3
12  3/25/2018          NaN                   2.0                      2
13  3/26/2018          NaN                   1.0                      1
14  3/27/2018    3/27/2018                   0.0                      0
```